# xmlrunner duplicates print statements for sub tests using unittest

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, allure

I am using a **xml test runner** for **unittest** https://github.com/xmlrunner/unittest-xml-reporting in order to generate XML files that I can pass for **Allure** framework. 
In one of my functions I use the sub test feature while iterating on a list (represented here as a range). 
I am running the code from the **command line** like such: **py test.py** 
I am trying to print in every sub test a specific statement to be catched in the output and passed to the XML file but for some reason the output that is being printed for every subtest is the **entire** test case output.
This is the code structure:

```
import sys
import datetime
import unittest
import xmlrunner


class TestSomeFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_some_func(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            with self.subTest(i):
                result = False
                print(i)
                self.assertTrue(result, msg="Failure")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    currentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    scriptName = sys.argv[0].split('.')[0]
    testResultsName = scriptName + '_' + currentTime

    unittest.main(
        testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='testResults/' + testResultsName),
        failfast=False, buffer=True, catchbreak=False, exit=False)
```

When I open the XML file the output is as such: 
[image] 
The range(1,10) is being printed for every sub test, instead of only the number of the sub test itself
I want for every sub test in the XML file to contain only the relevant printed statements.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the source code of the xmltestRunner , they have formatted the whole output of (system out) and the (system error) to the dom element. So that's reason you are getting the output of the whole system out contends in all the testcases it gets executes.

Sourcode in xmltestrunner

```
 def _report_output(test_runner, xml_testsuite, xml_document):
        """
        Appends the system-out and system-err sections to the XML document.
        """
        systemout = xml_document.createElement('system-out')
        xml_testsuite.appendChild(systemout)

        systemout_text = xml_document.createCDATASection(sys.stdout.getvalue())
        systemout.appendChild(systemout_text)

        systemerr = xml_document.createElement('system-err')
        xml_testsuite.appendChild(systemerr)

        systemerr_text = xml_document.createCDATASection(sys.stderr.getvalue())
        systemerr.appendChild(systemerr_text)
```

Source :
https://github.com/pycontribs/xmlrunner/blob/master/xmlrunner/xmlrunner.py

For example , if you execute the below piece of code

```
import sys
import datetime
import unittest
import xmlrunner
import random 

class TestSomeFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = list(range(10))

    def testCase(self,value):
        with self.subTest(value=value):
            result = False
            print("Input")
            print(value)
            self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))

    def test_some_func(self):
        for i in random.sample(self.seq, 10):
            self.testCase(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    currentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    scriptName = sys.argv[0].split('.')[0]
    testResultsName = scriptName + '_' + currentTime
    unittest.main(
        testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='testResults/' + testResultsName),
        failfast=False, buffer=True, catchbreak=False, exit=False)
```

your xml would look something like the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite errors="1" failures="10" file=".py" name="TestSomeFunc-20191118181814" skipped="0" tests="11" time="0.044" timestamp="2019-11-18T18:18:14">
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="18" name="test_some_func (value=1)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 1" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 16, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 1
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
1
Input
0
Input
7
Input
6
Input
2
Input
8
Input
4
Input
3
Input
9
Input
5
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="18" name="test_some_func (value=0)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 0" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 16, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 0
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
1
Input
0
Input
7
Input
6
Input
2
Input
8
Input
4
Input
3
Input
9
Input
5
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="18" name="test_some_func (value=7)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 7" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 16, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 7
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
1
Input
0
Input
7
Input
6
Input
2
Input
8
Input
4
Input
3
Input
9
Input
5
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="18" name="test_some_func (value=6)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 6" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 16, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 6
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
1
Input
0
Input
7
Input
6
Input
2
Input
8
Input
4
Input
3
Input
9
Input
5
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="18" name="test_some_func (value=2)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 2" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 16, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 2
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
1
Input
0
Input
7
Input
6
Input
2
Input
8
Input
4
Input
3
Input
9
Input
5
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="18" name="test_some_func (value=8)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 8" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 16, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 8
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
1
Input
0
Input
7
Input
6
Input
2
Input
8
Input
4
Input
3
Input
9
Input
5
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="18" name="test_some_func (value=4)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 4" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 16, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 4
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
1
Input
0
Input
7
Input
6
Input
2
Input
8
Input
4
Input
3
Input
9
Input
5
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="18" name="test_some_func (value=3)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 3" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 16, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 3
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
1
Input
0
Input
7
Input
6
Input
2
Input
8
Input
4
Input
3
Input
9
Input
5
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="18" name="test_some_func (value=9)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 9" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 16, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 9
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
1
Input
0
Input
7
Input
6
Input
2
Input
8
Input
4
Input
3
Input
9
Input
5
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="18" name="test_some_func (value=5)" time="0.037" timestamp="2019-11-18T18:18:14">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 5" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 16, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 5
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
1
Input
0
Input
7
Input
6
Input
2
Input
8
Input
4
Input
3
Input
9
Input
5
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="11" name="testCase" time="0.007" timestamp="2019-11-18T18:18:14">
        <error message="testCase() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'" type="TypeError">
<![CDATA[TypeError: testCase() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
]]>     </error>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

If you really need for which value its getting failed , you can use the the "msg" argument in assetTrue,Someting like this

```
self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
```

To be More Clear , if you add the print statement outside the test case also you can get the statement in every testcase , here below is the snippet to show the same.

```
import sys
import datetime
import unittest
import xmlrunner
import random 

class TestSomeFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = list(range(10))

    def testCase(self,value):
        with self.subTest(value=value):
            result = False
            self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))

    def test_some_func(self):
        for i in random.sample(self.seq, 10):
            self.testCase(i)
        print("Input")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    currentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    scriptName = sys.argv[0].split('.')[0]
    testResultsName = scriptName + '_' + currentTime
    unittest.main(
        testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='testResults/' + testResultsName),
        failfast=False, buffer=True, catchbreak=False, exit=False)
```

The XML Output for the above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite errors="1" failures="10" file=".py" name="TestSomeFunc-20191118182556" skipped="0" tests="11" time="0.014" timestamp="2019-11-18T18:25:56">
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="16" name="test_some_func (value=7)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 7" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 14, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 7
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="16" name="test_some_func (value=6)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 6" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 14, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 6
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="16" name="test_some_func (value=4)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 4" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 14, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 4
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="16" name="test_some_func (value=2)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 2" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 14, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 2
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="16" name="test_some_func (value=0)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 0" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 14, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 0
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="16" name="test_some_func (value=8)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 8" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 14, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 8
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="16" name="test_some_func (value=1)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 1" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 14, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 1
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="16" name="test_some_func (value=9)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 9" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 14, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 9
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="16" name="test_some_func (value=5)" time="0.000" timestamp="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 5" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 14, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 5
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="16" name="test_some_func (value=3)" time="0.007" timestamp="2019-11-18T18:25:56">
        <failure message="False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 3" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 14, in testCase
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(value))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 3
]]>     </failure>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[Input
]]>     </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="TestSomeFunc" file="sampleInstancetest.py" line="11" name="testCase" time="0.007" timestamp="2019-11-18T18:25:56">
        <error message="testCase() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'" type="TypeError">
<![CDATA[TypeError: testCase() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
]]>     </error>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>        </system-err>
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

A Small Workaround for printing the necessary message in console would be as below

```
import sys
import datetime
import unittest
import xmlrunner
import random 
import sys,string
import traceback           
import time

class TestSomeFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = list(range(10))

    def test_some_func(self):
        for index in random.sample(self.seq, 3):
            try:
                with self.subTest(index=index):
                   result = False
                   messsage = "stdout :: Test failed at index :: "+str(index)
                   print(messsage, file=sys.__stdout__)
                   self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(index))
            except AssertionError:
                print("Exception")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    currentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    scriptName = sys.argv[0].split('.')[0]
    testResultsName = scriptName + '_' + currentTime
    unittest.main(
        testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='testResults/' + testResultsName),
        failfast=False, buffer=True, catchbreak=False, exit=False)
```

Console output :

```
Running tests...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
stdout :: Test failed at index :: 4
stdout :: Test failed at index :: 0
stdout :: Test failed at index :: 5
F
======================================================================
FAIL [0.000s]: test_some_func (__main__.TestSomeFunc) (index=4)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 21, in test_some_func
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(index))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 4

======================================================================
FAIL [0.000s]: test_some_func (__main__.TestSomeFunc) (index=0)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 21, in test_some_func
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(index))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 0

======================================================================
FAIL [0.014s]: test_some_func (__main__.TestSomeFunc) (index=5)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleInstancetest.py", line 21, in test_some_func
    self.assertTrue(result, msg='Test failed for the case :: {0}'.format(index))
AssertionError: False is not true : Test failed for the case :: 5

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.014s

FAILED (failures=3)

Generating XML reports...
```

Source : 
https://github.com/xmlrunner/unittest-xml-reporting/issues/156
https://github.com/xmlrunner/unittest-xml-reporting/pull/166

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am already showing the value using the `msg` for displaying the value I catch, I was just wondering if there is something I am missing about the way I am printing in the sub tests. I am trying to print for each sub test a custom statement because I want it to be shown in the Allure.